# Spring cloud multiple RestTemplate

Tags: spring, cloud, resttemplate, netflix-ribbon

I am using spring cloud: Spring Boot Application with Eureka + Ribbon default configuration.

I am using 2 `RestTemplate` configurations, both are `@LoadBalanced` currently and both of them have the same `UriTemplateHandler`.

I declared both the `@SpringBootApplication` and also the `@RibbonClient(name="${service.name}")` annotations.

My problem is:

When I am trying to access the first configured `RestTemplate`, the `RestTemplate` resolvs (by eureka and load balancing by ribbon) to a server , not as I requested as configured in the `UriTemplateHandler`.

For example: in the `UriTemplateHandler` I configured "A-Service" and in real time the `restTemplate` sends the `httpRequest` to "B-Service"
This behavior happens often, not just for a specific request, but it looks like it only happens when I'm accessing the first configured `RestTemplate`.

Is it a problem to use 2 RestTemplate with the same uri?

I have no idea why it happens, please advise.

Answer (score 9):

When creating these rest templates as beans, name them uniquely, like e.g.

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean("integrationRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
   // build and return your rest template 
   return ....
}
```

Then, the other one might be without any specific name e.g.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Now, if you have these two distinctive rest templates, you can inject the former one e.g. like that:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ApplicantService(@Qualifier("integrationRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

// service methods
...
}
```

Basically, the point is you can choose whatever rest template you want, by specifying a @Qualifier.